# Is there a general catch all way to pre-emptive console.log all DOM reflow?

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, dom, google-chrome-devtools

We have a complex SPA, and we have so many needed nodes in the DOM (we've minimized it to the max already) that occasionally debugging very buried code which triggers a reflow (beit CSS or JavaScript) is very difficult.

We use performance traces and timeline often but they don't always help and we started to wonder to get to reflow buts faster. Does anyone have a way to capture or console.log lines of code or CSS properties in a huge code base that are the culprits of reflow with a catch-all snippet that would breakpoint the just caused reflow?

Then we can breakpoint and work right on the source straight away. Cordova app so lighthouse audits just crash browser.